# How to structure Javascript programs in complex web applications?

Tags: javascript, architecture, web-applications

I have a problem, which is not easily described. I'm writing a web application that makes strong usage of jQuery and AJAX calls. Now I don't have a lot of experience in Javascript archicture, but I realize that my program has not a good structure. I think I have too many identifiers referring to the same (at least more or less) thing.

Let's have an look at an arbitrary exemplary UI widget that  makes up a tiny part of the application: The widget may be a part of a window and the window may be a part of a window manager:

1. The eventhandlers use DOM elements as parameters. The DOM element represents a widget in the browser.
2. A lot of times I use jQuery objects (Basically wrappers around DOM elements) to do something with the widget. Sometimes they are used transiently, sometimes they are stored in a variable for later purposes.
3. The AJAX function calls use string identifiers for these widgets. They are processed server side.
4. Beside that I have a widget class whose instances represent a widget. It is instantiated through the new operator.

Now I have somehow four different object identifiers for the same thing, which needs to be kept in sync until the page is loaded anew. This seems not to be a good thing.

#### Any advice?

**EDIT:**
*@Will Morgan*: It's a form designer that allows to create web forms within the browser. The backend is Zope, a python web application server. It's difficult to get more explicit as this is a general problem I observe all the time when doing Javascript development with the trio jQuery, DOM tree and my own prototyped class instances.

**EDIT2:**
I think it would helpful to  make an example, albeit an artificial one. Below you see a logger widget that can be used to add a block element to a web page in which logged items are displayed.

```
makeLogger = function(){
     var rootEl = document.createElement('div');
     rootEl.innerHTML = 'Logged items:';
     rootEl.setAttribute('class', 'logger');

     var append = function(msg){
           // append msg as a child of root element.
           var msgEl = document.createElement('div');
           msgEl.innerHTML = msg;
           rootEl.appendChild(msgEl);
     };

     return {
          getRootEl: function() {return rootEl;},
          log      : function(msg) {append(msg);}
     };
};

// Usage 
var logger = makeLogger();
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.appendChild(logger.getRootEl());
logger.log('What\'s up?');
```

At this point I have a wrapper around the HTMLDivElement (the hosted object). With having the logger instance (the native object) at hand I can easily work with it through the function *logger.getRootEl()*.
Where I get stuck is when I only have the DOM element at hand and need to do something with the public API returned by function *makeLogger* (e.g. in event handlers). And this is where the mess starts. I need to hold all the native objects in a repository or something so that I can retrieve again. It would be so much nicer to have a connection (e.g. a object property) from the hosted object back to my native object.
I know it can be done, but it has some drawbacks:

- These kind of (circular) references are potentially memory leaking up to IE7
- When to pass the *hosted object* and when to pass the *native object* (in functions)?

For now, I do the back referencing with jQuery's data() method. But all in all I don't like the way I have to keep track of the relation between the hosted object and its native counterpart.

#### How do you handle this scenario?

**EDIT3:**
After some insight I've gained from Anurag's example..
*@Anurag:* If I've understood your example right, the critical point is to set up the correct (what's correct depends on your needs, though) ***execution context*** for the event handlers. And this is in your case the presentation object instance, which is done with Mootool's bind() function. So you ensure that you're *ALWAYS* dealing with the wrapper object (I've called it the native object) instead of the DOM object, right?


***A note for the reader:*** You're not forced to use Mootools to achieve this. In jQuery, you would setup your event handlers with the *$.proxy()* function, or if you're using plain old Javascript, you would utilize the *apply* property that every function exposes.

Comment: What kind of web app is it? Got any examples so we can help?

Comment: So in plainer language, "how should one structure code and data that composes/infers/performs suitable responses to a changing set of UI elements' events - and copes with dynamic changes to what is in the set of elements - where for IE memory management reasons the elements need to be referred to by other objects and functions indirectly through keys/names (rather than potentially circular direct references between objects) - and the elements have multiple keys/names; and the elements also have both extra custom wrapper classes and also jQuery wrapper classes"?

Comment: @martinr: You're kidding at me, aren't you? How can such a monster scentence be plainer? Maybe it's because I'm not a native speaker :)

Comment: LOL okay shorter not plainer.

Comment: that is korrect! The library does not matter. You could use any library or POJOs (plain ol' Javascript objects) to do the same thing. But the important thing like you said is setting up the `execution context` to the native object (or anywhere else who is buddies with the native object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the four objects that need to be synchronized, you could have a single object and pass the reference around in a constructor, or as function arguments.

The way I fix this problem is to never lose a reference to the wrapper object. Whenever a DOM object is needed (for example inserting into the page), this wrapper object provides it. But sticking that widget onto the screen, the wrapper object sets up all event handling and AJAX handling code specific to the widget, so the reference the the wrapper is maintained at all times in these event handlers and AJAX callbacks.

I've created a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/YHcTv/5/) on jsfiddle using MooTools that might make sense to you.

Comment: I think this is very close to my core problem. I'll investigate your example more thoroughly. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a global registry:

```
window.WidgetRegistry = {};
window.WidgetRegistry['foowidget'] = new Widget('#myID');
```

and when AJAX calls return, they can get the widget like this:

```
var widgetID = data.widgetID;
if (widgetID in window.WidgetRegistry) {
    var widget = window.WidgetRegistry[widgetID];
}
```

For your jQuery calls: I'd guess they are relatively inexpensive, since jQuery caches objects for later use. But you could extend the above suggested `WidgetRegistry` by using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
var $widget = $('#myWidget');
var widgetID = 'foo';
$widget.data('widget', widgetID);
```

In this way, you can store the widget ID attached to each jQuery object and re-access it from the global registry.

Testing, if an jQuery object has an existing widget:

```
return $('#test').data('widget') &&
       ($('#test').data('widget') in window.WidgetRegistry);
```

Note, that these are just suggestions. Actually, there are dozens of ways to achieve a consolidation like this. If you want to combine your code deeper with jQuery, you could [extend the jQuery object](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), so that you could write something like:

```
$('#widget').widget({'foo':'bar'});
// and/or
var allWidgets = $('*:widget');
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've fully understood your question, but I'll try to point some ideas.

In my opinion, you should make base widget class, which contains common functionality for widgets.

Let's use for example AppName.Widgets.base(). One of the instance variables is _events, which is object that stores events as keys and function as values. That way each class defines the events for this widget, and you can easily bind them in the constructor. As for the string identifiers, the easiest way is to use toString().

Example:

```
namespace('AppName.Widgets'); // you can find implementations easy

AppName.Widgets.base = function() {
    if (!this._type) return;

    this._dom = $('div.widget.'+this._type);
    for (var e in this._events) {
        this._dom.bind(e, this._events[e]);
    }

    this.toString = function() { return this._type; };
}

AppName.Widgets.example = function() { // extends AppName.Widgets.base
    this._type   = 'example';
    this._events = { 'click' : function(e) { alert('click'); }  };

    AppName.Widgets.base.call(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what you can or can't do will depend on how much control you have over the javascript. Personally I often have to use libraries built by others so I might only get a DOM node to work with, but I really need my object instead. In these cases I find using the data feature in jQuery is very handy. By using the data feature, you can 'store' your object inside the DOM node to retrieve it later.

Given your example above, here's how you could use the data feature to get back your widget after having functions that only use the DOM node.

```
makeLogger = function(){
     var rootEl = document.createElement('div');
     rootEl.innerHTML = 'Logged items:';
     rootEl.setAttribute('class', 'logger');

     var append = function(msg){
           // append msg as a child of root element.
           var msgEl = document.createElement('div');
           msgEl.innerHTML = msg;
           rootEl.appendChild(msgEl);
     };

     var self = {
          getRootEl: function() {return rootEl;},
          log      : function(msg) {append(msg);}
     };

    // Save a copy to the domNode
    $(rootEl).data("logger", self);
    return self;
};

// Example of only getting the dom node
function whatsUp (domNode){
   // Get the logger from the domNode
   $(domNode).data('logger').log('What\'s up?');
}

// Usage
var logger = makeLogger();
var loggerNode = logger.getRootEl();
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.appendChild(loggerNode);
whatsUp(loggerNode);
```

Comment: i think the OP is using the data API currently to associate objects to 
DOM nodes.

Comment: Yes, this is what I do when I say: "For now, I do the back referencing with jQuery's data() method. But all in all I don't like the way I have to keep track of the relation between the hosted object and its native counterpart." But nevertheless I hardly find it elegant.